# Importing XML didn't finish, site is now inaccessible

Tags: multisite

I have a network of 12 sites, I tried importing an XML for the main site, and it was taking hours, so I simply closed the page.

Today I find that I can't access this site, but I can access all the other ones in the network. And I can't actually access the /network either.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you can neither access front or back end?

Comment: You assume right, but I fixed it by restoring from an sql backup, wish I knew exactly what went wrong... but this works.

Comment: potentially a database corruption then, good thing you had a backup. Have you checked how large a file you can import / tried the wordpress importer plugin to prevent this happening in future?